# How to show $\sum_{k=n}^\infty{\frac{1}{k!}} \leq \frac{2}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series, factorial

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty{\frac{1}{k!}} \leq \frac{2}{n!}$$

Can someone show why this estimate holds true? I tried quite a bit but couldn't really find a way to approach this. 
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28k%29!+from+k%3Dn+to+infty+%3C+2%2F%28n%29!) says it is true but I don't know what the gamma function is.

$$ \sum_{k=n}^\infty{\frac{1}{k!}} = \frac{1}{n!} + \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$$
So then I need to show that$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty{\frac{1}{k!}} \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!} ~~\Big[\leq \frac{1}{n!}\Big]$$

Is it possible to do this by induction? I don't really know how to approach this now.

Comment: Just in case: the inequality doesn't hold for $n = 0$. For $n \geqslant 1$, note that $(n+k)! \geqslant n!\cdot (n+1)^k$.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}}\le\frac{2}{n!}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e-\frac{e\Gamma(n,1)}{\Gamma(n)}\le\frac{2}{n!}\space\text{for}\space n>-1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to show that $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \le \frac{1}{n!}$$

For all $k \ge n+1$, we have $$k! \ge 2^{k-n} \cdot n!$$

Therefore, we have $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n! \cdot 2^{k-n}} = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} = \frac{1}{n!}$$

Comment: Does the inequality $k! \geq 2^{k-n} \cdot n!$ have a name? I think I need to prove that in order to use it.

Comment: Not really. For a proof note that $\frac{k!}{n!} = k(k-1) \cdots (n+1) \ge 2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2 = 2^{n-k}$. Of course, this doesn't hold when $n=0$, so you need to exclude that.

Comment: Okay thanks. Since in my case I substitute $n$ for $n+1$ anyway $n=0$ does not cause issues. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

$$
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} = \frac{1}{n!} \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \ldots \bigg) < \frac{1}{n!} \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \ldots \bigg)\\
= \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n} = \frac{1}{n!} \cdot \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n} \bigg)
$$
Now compare this expression to what you have on the RHS: certain terms cancel out. What do you get?

Comment: Small typo, that $k$ should start from $n$, not $n+1$.

Comment: yeah, that's how I solved it anyway

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{1}{(k+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{(k-1)!}(\dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+1}) \leq \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}(\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1})$$ when $k\geq n$

So

$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(k+1)!} \leq \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=n}^\infty (\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}) = \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!} *\frac{1}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n!}$$