# Showing that $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac {1}{k!} < \frac {1}{N!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, factorial

I was constructing a proof through inequalities, but I am having a bit of problem showing the following step:  $$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac {1}{k!} < \frac {1}{N!}$$

Is there any quick way to show this?

Comment: Can you use the power series expansion of the exponential function, and that $2<e<3$

Comment: Yes, we can the power series expansion, but we have not shown yet that $2 < e < 3$

Comment: Hit: the sequence decreases faster than a geometric progression of common ratio $1/(k+1)$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221084/c-n-1-frac11-frac12-frac1n-so-prove-e-c-n-le, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557954/how-to-show-sum-k-n-infty-frac1k-leq-frac2n

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac {1}{k!} =\frac{1}{N!}\left(\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}+...\right)<$$
$$<\frac{1}{N!}\left(\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{(N+1)^2}+...\right)=\frac{1}{N!}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{N+1}}{1-\frac{1}{N+1}}\leq \frac {1}{N!}$$

Comment: My edit was to correct the last "$<$" to "$\leq$" (e.g. if $N=1$) which does not affect the validity of the proof because of the strict inequality in the first line......+1

Answer (score 11):

An alternative proof:

$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac1{k!}<\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac{k-1}{k!}=\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac1{(k-1)!}-\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac1{k!}=\frac1{N!}$$

Comment: Kinda cute................

Comment: @Daniel I remembered the series of the RHS from the Cantor [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Fractional_values) to represent numbers in $(0,1)$. Unfortunately Im not as smart as it seems, just memory.

Answer (score 4):

All we need to prove is :

$$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac {N!}{k!} < 1$$

Now, since

$$\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}+\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)} \ldots <\frac{1}{(N+1)}+\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}+\frac{1}{(N+2)(N+3)}$$

Can you see the telescoping sum now, doing that we get

$$\frac{1}{N+1}+\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}+\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)} \ldots <\frac{2}{N+1} < 1 ~\forall ~N \ge 2$$